# Irrelevant job match

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I subscribed to job alerts about "Mid-level remote php jobs" and just received this single recommendation - https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/161412/manual-qa-remote-mall-connect

It is manual QA job, and the only occurence of `php` word is in their description of nice-to-have's of their candidate.

Can I please receive relevant matches, and maybe only receive so distanly related when I have no matches for a really long time?

Comment: A "competitive salary" of $10-12k for six hours of work a day, with a monthly renewable contract. Oh joy. I bet the nice Macbook and the bottomless fridge are reserved for the folks in the Amsterdam office and not the remote workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding here - this isn't a bug. You subscribed to a job alert which is effectively the same as a performing a search on the site. These aren't recommendations - they're literally the backend running your search query for you and returning the results.

In this case you're doing a text search and that includes things which might only have a slight relation to what you're searching for. E.g. a single reference to PHP would be enough to trigger this alert. Alerts will return exactly the same thing as if you ran the search in the /jobs site itself.

The job in question has the following text within it:

> Experience in Selenium Webdriver with PHP

And that's why it appeared in the search results.

If you want specificity then I'd suggest using the filter functionality which guarantees that the job matches on the specific fields you're interested in:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?tl=php+&r=true&ms=MidLevel